# Reactjs Google OAuth login with custom UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, google-oauth, customization

I am trying to use a custom button/UI for my login page with google oauth. I couldn't find any tutorial on how to setup google oauth without using the react-google-login package. I don't want to use the built-in button components that come with the package. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login

The npm package has options to customize the button